# switch example as idiomatic boost::hana

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, c++17, boost-hana

Can the [real world example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-quickstart-any) of the introduction build without falling back to raw recursion?

> Of course, we could probably intertwine Hana algorithms in a convoluted way to achieve this, …

Why has this to be so convoluted? - I guess generating code like this example happens quite often.

I did some research into the project and with Google but could not find any alternative implementations.

I experimented on my own:

```cpp
template <typename Any>
auto switch_(Any& a) {
  return [&a](auto ...cases_) {
    auto cases = hana::make_tuple(cases_...);
    auto default_ = hana::find_if(cases, [](auto const& c) {
      return hana::first(c) == hana::type_c<default_t>;
    });
    static_assert(default_ != hana::nothing, "switch is missing a default_ case");
    auto rest = hana::filter(cases, [](auto const& c) {
      return hana::first(c) != hana::type_c<default_t>;
    });
    auto& type_idx = a.type();
    auto found = hana::find_if(rest, [&](auto const& c) {
      using T = int; // typename decltype(+hana::first(c))::type;
      return hana::bool_c<typeid(int) == type_idx>;
      // return hana::bool_c<false>;
    });
    if constexpr (found == hana::nothing) {
        return hana::second(*default_)();
    }
    else {
        using T = typename decltype(+hana::first(*found))::type;
        return hana::second(*found)(*boost::unsafe_any_cast<T>(&a));
    }
  };
}
```

The `find_if` is not able to be resolved at compile time as `type_idx` is only known at runtime.

The general `hana::fold_left` should be able to do the trick. But I could not figure out how I can transport all the details and auto deduce the return type.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: There's no way to avoid iterating over the entire `rest` tuple without recursion; breaking out of the iteration early based on runtime-only logic is not something that can be done with Hana algos, which rely on compile-time predicates. So the answer is, you _could_ accomplish this with `fold_left`, but it wouldn't have the exact same semantics and would perform linearly worse per supplied case.

Comment: (N.b. Hana does contain algorithms that support runtime predicates to break iteration, such as `any_of`, but these are for entirely different purposes and it would be confusing to misuse them for our purposes. These are the "convoluted ways" referred to in the documentation.)

Comment: What this showcases is the fact that we need a programatic way of creating a switch statement in C++, which is unfortunately beyond Hana alone.

Comment: @Louis : Indeed. [Boost.Switch](http://dancinghacker.com/switch/) ([code](http://dancinghacker.com/switch/switch.hpp)) was provisionally accepted [9 (!) years ago](http://osdir.com/ml/lib.boost.announce/2008-01/msg00003.html) now – too bad it never made it those last few crucial steps... It's probably showing its age to an unacceptable degree now anyway.

Comment: Too bad for C++. Let's hope for C++20 and better compile time tools.